# SQLAlchemy: pool_size and SQLite

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

The code

`create_engine(sqlite:////infodb/timestamp.db', pool_size=10)`

works fine in SQLAlchemy version 0.6.3. However, it does not work in version 0.7.1.

The error message I am getting is as follows

> TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'pool_size' sent to create_engine(),
>   using configuration SQLiteDialect_pysqlite/NullPool/Engine.  Please
>   check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination
>   of components.

In version 0.7.1 the default value of the `poolclass` variable is an instance of `sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool`. In turn, the `NullPool` object does not accept `pool_size` variable. In version 0.6.3, `poolclass` was an instance of `sqlalchemy.pool.SingletonThreadPool` and thus there was no problem dealing with `pool_size`.

As a result, version SQLAlchemy 0.7.1 is **not backward-compatible** with 0.6.3. So I wondering, what is the reason for going from `SingletonThreadPool` to `NullPool`? It breaks the user's code.

Comment: SQLAlchemy major releases are not backwards compatible in many other ways too. At a guess: SQLite doesn't need a threadpool?

Comment: Yes, SQLAlchemy does not need threadpool but we don't know "a priori" what type of database I will deal with. In most cases it is Oracle but in some it is SQLite. Putting 'pool_size' for everything was fine but not it breaks the code.

Comment: just an FYI, SQLAlchemy version changes from 0.X to 0.Y always contain many backwards incompatible changes, you can review them in the documentation: [whats new in SQLAlchemy 0.7?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/changelog/migration_07.html) [SQLite now uses nullpool for file-based databases](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/changelog/migration_07.html#sqlite-the-sqlite-dialect-now-uses-nullpool-for-file-based-databases)

Comment: Also, using the "pool_size" argument in 0.6 across both non-sqlite and sqlite database URLs is a bad idea as well.  0.6 uses an entirely different pool style for SQLite which means pool_size has totally different semantics.   Different database backends will always require different configurational tweaks, it's best to have application code be sensitive to this, storing both the URL and a set of tuning **kwargs to use for each type of database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [SQLAlchemy 0.7 What's New document](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/changelog/migration_07.html#sqlite-the-sqlite-dialect-now-uses-nullpool-for-file-based-databases):

> #### SQLite - the SQLite dialect now uses `NullPool` for file-based databases
>
> This change is **99.999% backwards compatible**, unless you are using temporary tables across connection pool connections.
>
> A file-based SQLite connection is blazingly fast, and using `NullPool` means that each call to `Engine.connect` creates a new pysqlite connection.
>
> Previously, the `SingletonThreadPool` was used, which meant that all connections to a certain engine in a thread would be the same connection. It’s intended that the new approach is more intuitive, particularly when multiple connections are used.
>
> `SingletonThreadPool` is still the default engine when a `:memory:` database is used.
>
> Note that this change **breaks temporary tables used across Session commits**, due to the way SQLite handles temp tables. See the note at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dialects/sqlite.html#using-temporary-tables-with-sqlite if temporary tables beyond the scope of one pool connection are desired.
>
> [#1921](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/1921)

Major SQLAlchemy releases (so between 0.5 and 0.6 or 0.6 to 0.7) so far have always included backwards incompatible changes as major ideas are being worked out. 0.7 is no exception, see the [Backwards Incompatible API Changes section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/changelog/migration_07.html#backwards-incompatible-api-changes).

You can still provide a different pool class if you have to, by passing a `poolclass` keyword in with the `connect` call:

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import SingletonThreadPool

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydb.db', poolclass=SingletonThreadPool)
```

Passing in an explicit pool class also works on 0.6. Personally, I'd use exception handling here:

```
try:
    engine = create_engine(URL, pool_size=10)
except TypeError:
    # The pool_size argument won't work for the default SQLite setup in SQLAlchemy 0.7, try without
    engine = create_engine(URL)
```

Comment: @zzzeek: :-) It's those decimal points that trip you up, don't they?